# ClickOnce - Security Questions

Tags: winforms, clickonce

I am considering using ClickOnce for a legacy Windows Forms application. I have several questions related to ClickOnce itself.

1. Does a user need administrative privelages to install the ClickOnce application?
2. Can the ClickOnce application access the local file system?
3. When does an end-user experience security prompts?
4. Can the application be served over https://?
5. Can the application make calls to services hosted on https://?
6. Can the application be served over SSL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. No
2. Yes
3. When the app is updated (optionally, you can suppress them)
4. Yes
5. Yes
6. See #4? I'm not sure what you're asking, HTTPS = HTTP over SSL